# Apache 2 + mod_wsgi + WSGIScriptAlias

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I am currently doing research whether Python and Django are fit for a project that I'm going to work on (so far it looks good). As a means of a test, I want to get python running on an actual server (apache2 on ubuntu), using mod_wsgi, but I just can't make it work. Here is my httpd.conf (located at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test/tc-test/ /var/www/stage/hello/tc-test/django.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/stage/test/tc-test/

<Directory /var/www/stage/test/tc-test>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

My django.wsgi looks as follows:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/stage/test/tc-test')

os_environment['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The url for this directory will be http://stage.website.com/test/tc-test

Strangely enough, when I reboot the apache server, I keep getting 500 internal server errors. Not just for that subdirectory, but for all other subdirectories on the server. I looked at the apache error log, but for some reason no error is being logged at all. I managed to narrow down the culprits to WSGIScriptAlias and WSGIPythonPath: when I remove both of them, the 500 internal server errors disappear, and when I add any of them, they appear again. I have confirmed that mod_wsgi is working like it should, and it's probably something very simple that I'm looking over. I just can't find out what. Any help on this?

Comment: For starters you're referencing `django.wsgi` and `wsgi.py`… which is it?

Comment: hmm, good point. The current file I use is django.wsgi

Comment: You also need to ensure apache has appropriate permissions. Consult your apache error log.

Comment: Okay, I am an idiot. I indeed changed that part, and the internal server errors are gone. Apparently my first attempt to make this work failed, after which I tried a different guide, which had a different name of "django.wsgi", and I forgot to change that part too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test/tc-test /var/www/stage/hello/tc-test/django.wsgi
```

You shouldn't have trailing slash on first argument.

Comment: Maybe not the answer for the OP, but it seems to have been _my_ problem. Thanks :)